# base word to generate affix word

Tags: python, dataframe, affix

i have 2 dataframes, one is base word and another is affixed word, how do i give base word input and output the affixed word??

```
import pandas as pd

# Membuat dataframe sederhana
df = pd.DataFrame({'nama': ['menghubung', 'mencinta', 'mengajar', 'mengoles','menyejajarkan']})


hasil_pencarian = df['nama'].str.contains('ajar')

# Menampilkan baris yang sesuai dengan hasil pencarian
print(df[hasil_pencarian])
```

this is wrong, it's just looking to find if the character is in the dataframe

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: if i give input ajar the result will be 'mengajar' because 'mengajar' is base word of 'ajar', whereas 'menyejajarkan' is 'sejajar'

Comment: use `str.endswith()` instead of `str.contains()`

Comment: @NehalBirla its still wrong and the result is nothing

Comment: Please provide your actual code, input and output in the question. According to what I understand you need to find the words in dataframe which has the given suffix. For example if i am given `'ajar'` as the suffix the code should return `'mengajar'`. If I understand correctly then just changing `hasil_pencarian = df['nama'].str.contains('ajar')` to `hasil_pencarian = df['nama'].str.endswith('ajar')` should solve the problem.